# Prove $\nabla u \times \nabla v =0$ is a necessary and sufficient condition that $u$ and $v$ are functionally related by the equation $F(u,v) = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Let $u$ and $v$ be differentiable functions of $x$,  $y$ and $z$. Show
>   that a necessary and sufficient condition that $u$ and $v$ are
>   functionally related by the equation $F(u,v) = 0$ is that $$\nabla u
>  \times \nabla v =0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given two functions $u$ and $v$ that are "functionally dependent" the function $F$ exhibiting this dependence is not uniquely determined: The same dependence can  be written, e.g., as $F(u,v):=u^2+v^2-1=0$ or as $G(u,v):=v-\sqrt{1-u^2}=0$. In the following I shall  write the dependence in the form $v=f(u)$ for some function $f$ of type ${\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$. The following theorem is of a purely local nature.

**Theorem.** Assume that $u$, $v: \Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ are smooth in an open set $\Omega\subset {\mathbb R}^3$, and that $\nabla u(p)\ne0$. Then the following are equivalent:

(a)$\ \quad \nabla u(x)\times\nabla v(x)\equiv0$ in a suitable neighborhood $U$ of $p$,

(b)$\quad$ There is a smooth real-valued function $f$ such that $$v(x)\equiv f\bigl(u(x)\bigr)\tag{1}$$ $\quad\quad\ $ in a suitable neighborhood $U$ of $p$.

*Proof.* The part (b)$\Rightarrow$(a) is easy: From $v=f\circ u$ we obtain, using the chain rule,
$$\nabla v(x)= f'\bigl(u(x)\bigr)\>\nabla u(x)\qquad\forall x\in U\ .$$
Here $\lambda(x):=f'\bigl(u(x)\bigr)$ is a scalar function. This immediately implies (a).

In order to prove (a)$\Rightarrow$(b) we begin by proving that $v$ is constant on the level surfaces of $u$. Since $\nabla u(p)\ne0$ we may assume that $u_3(x)\ne 0$ in a suitable neighborhood of $p$. The implicit function theorem then allows to solve the equation $$\bigl(H(x_1,x_2,x_3,\bar u):=\bigr)\quad u(x_1,x_2,x_3)-\bar u=0\tag{2}$$ for $x_3$ in a four-dimensional window $W$ with center $\bigl(p_1,p_2,p_3,u(p)\bigr)$: There is a smooth function $\psi$ such that $(2)$ is equivalent with
$$x_3=\psi(x_1,x_2,\bar u)\tag{3}$$
in $W$. For given $\bar u$ near $u(p)$  this equation represents the level set $N_{\bar u}: \ u(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\bar u$ as a graph over the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane, and $(3)$ tells us that $N_{\bar u}$ is indeed a smooth surface.

Consider now a curve $\gamma: \> t\mapsto x(t)\in N_{\bar u}$. Then $\phi(t):=u\bigl(x(t)\bigr)$ has constant value $\bar u$. It follows that $$\nabla u\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\cdot x'(t)=\phi'(t)\equiv0\ .$$
We now look at the value of $v$ along $\gamma$, i.e., consider the function $\chi(t):=v\bigl(x(t)\bigr)$.
Since by our assumption (a) we know that $\nabla v(x)=\lambda(x)\nabla u(x)$ for a certain function $\lambda(\cdot)$ we find that
$$\chi'(t)=\nabla v\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\cdot x'(t)=\lambda(x)\>\nabla u\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\cdot x'(t)\equiv0\ .$$
This shows that $v$ is constant along $\gamma$, whence on all of $N_{\bar u}$.

It follows that the value of $v$ is completely determined by the value $\bar u$ of $u$, so that there is indeed a function $f$ such that $(1)$ holds. It remains to prove that this $f$ is smooth. To this end we invoke $(3)$. For all $(x_1,x_2,\bar u)$ the point $\bigl(x_1,x_2,\psi(x_1,x_2,\bar u)\bigr)$ lies in $N_{\bar u}$. We therefore have
$$f(\bar u)=v\bigl(x_1,x_2,\psi(x_1,x_2,\bar u)\bigr)\ ,$$
where the dependence on $x_1$, $x_2$ on the right hand side is only apparent.

Comment: How do i prove that it is a necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I've inserted an "(a)$\Rightarrow$(b)" where the proof of this part begins.

Comment: i understood till (3)
pls keep aside complex notations[$\gamma :$ curve and $N_{\bar {u}}$]. What i understood:- $x_3 = \psi (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ 
$\psi $ function exist and $x_3$ has partial derivates with respect to $x_1, x_2, \bar{u}$

Where i did not understood:

A) how can we say $\bar{u}$ is constant? (i just know $x_3$ can be implicitly expressed and has partial derivates(thus $\psi$ becomes smooth surface) in terms of $x_1, x_2$ and $\bar{u}$)

Comment: B) if we get $\bar {u}$ = constant then $d (u(\bar{r})) = \nabla u(\bar{r}). d\bar r = d\bar{u} = 0$ 
where $\bar {r} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$

using this it follows that $d (v(\bar{r})) = 0 \implies v(\bar r) = constant $




(C)what i did not undertand from here is how it follows $f(u,v) = 0$

Kindly enlighten

Comment: @ChristianBlatter can you pls have a look at above my 2 points.

Comment: @anirudhb: See my edits. Note that $\bar u$ is not $x_3$ but an additional variable.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I understood the proof but at 1 point.
while $x(t)$ changes, how $u(x(t)) = \bar{u} =$ constant ($\bar{u}$ depends on x(t)) even while $x(t)$ varies. Pls clarify

Comment: @ChristianBlatter if $\bar {u} $ is assumed to be constant, then in the beginning itself, can we say $du = d\bar{u} = 0 \implies \nabla u \cdot \vec{r} = 0$ ($\vec r = (x_1,x_2, x_3)$). So do we need to apply implicit function theorem then